# OpenCart Version 3.0.3.8 with Journal Theme 3 - Login Popup doesn't always direct to the correct page

Tags: opencart

When an existing client opens my page and click on the Login button to login, the are presented with a Login Popup where they can insert their email address and password. The pop up also has a Login button. When pressed, it either informs the client that the details are incorrect or just closes and the client is then logged in. The issue I have is that occasionally (maybe 7 out of 10) the pop up doesn't close but instead it loads the whole home page within it's boarders. We can see that the customer has successfully logged in. The process is then to close that pop up and refresh the website to continue.

I have only just experienced this and do not have official support form the Journal theme team. I have tried their documentation but it's not clear how this particular pop up works. I was wondering if someone here had a similar issue.